# Convert int-timestamp to timestamp (while updating rows)

Tags: mysql, join, timestamp, sql-update

I have added a new column that should store a `timestamp` value. This value currently exists in another table. So I tried to build a query to update my new column using the other table.

This is my current query:

```
    UPDATE `gc_users` U 
    SET    `registration_date` = ( SELECT `joindate` 
                                   FROM    `vb_user` 
                                   WHERE   `username` = U.`name` 
                                   LIMIT 0,1
                                 )
```

The problem is that after updating `registration_date` the value is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

New table: `gc_users`

- Column: registration_date  ( timestamp )
- Example: *`2013-01-11 15:24:04`*

Source table: `va_user`

- Column: joindate ( int )
- Example: *`1354290120`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `FROM_UNIXTIME`

```
UPDATE  `gc_users` U
         INNER JOIN `vb_user` a
            ON a.`username` = U.`name`
SET     u.`registration_date` = FROM_UNIXTIME(a.`joindate`)
LIMIT   0,1
```

- [FROM_UNIXTIME](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)